# How to build a form in the backend in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a `HtmlHelper` extension that would build a `form` in the backend.

Something like this:

```
public static IHtmlContent HiddenFormFor<TModel, TResult>(
        this IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression,
        string buttonDescription)
{
    var builder = new HtmlContentBuilder();
    // This is the part that doesn't fit, I just copied how it's done in the view:
    using(htmlHelper.BeginForm("index", "home"))
    {
        builder.AppendHtml(htmlHelper.HiddenFor(expression));
        builder.AppendHtml($"<span type=\"submit\" class=\"label label-primary\">{htmlHelper.Raw(buttonDescription)}</span>");
    }
    return builder;
}
```

The problem with this is that I don't know how to get the elements built with `BeginForm` and `EndForm` and put them into the `builder`.

Comment: Is it not a better idea to use partial views for this? Then you could just use Razor

Comment: @StijnvanGaal Good idea, thanks. I was trying to put all the logic together in a single class as `IHtmlHelper` extensions, so I still would like to know if there is a way to do it in the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i already suggested in the comments: Just use `partial views`

But as you still request to know how to use it in the backend. Seems like you should look into how `Razor` works ;) With `Razor` you are still calling methods from classes in namespaces. `BeginForm` is a method from the `FormExtensions`.

So you could do the following:

```
...
Using System.Web.Mvc.Html;


public static IHtmlContent HiddenFormFor<TModel, TResult>(
        this IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression,
        string buttonDescription)
{
    var content = new StringBuilder();
    content.Append(FormExtensions.BeginForm(htmlHelper)); //adding <form> to htmlhelper
    content.append(htmlHelper.HiddenFor(expression)); //Add hidden value
    content.append(FormExtensions.EndForm(htmlHelper)); //adding </form> to htmlHelper

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(content.ToString());

}
```

**EDIT**
Looking into it a bit more i found what i think should be the solution. Check the code above

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried that, but I got stuck on "how to fill the form". The methods of the form don't seem to allow to "add inputs tot he form" in the backend....

Comment: I updated the answer with a new way. I believe this should work

Comment: I was just testing the code. Can I ask what do I need to reference to reach both `FormExtensions` and `MvcHtmlString` ?

Comment: 'FormExtensions' exists in 'System.Web.Mvc.Html' and 'MvcHtmlString' in 'System.Web.Mvc'. But please sir. try search these things yourself